# Android internal testing app download is not functionable

Tags: android

After uploading my app .aap to internal testing and downloading from Google Play, nothing on my app works - login worked couple of times, then it stopped, search engine doesn’t work at all, it looks like most https requests are not working, while everything works just fine when installing app from AndroidStudio.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the universally signed APK? You must also uninstall the app installed by Android Studio, since the APK does not have the same certificate.

Downloading and installing from Google Play seems not to work always.

Comment: Sure, I uninstalled the app from Samsung, then I went to the link that was provided by internal testing (something like https://play.google.com/apps/test/myappbundle/8 ) and it allowed me to download the app automatically switching to Google Play. I had no other options, like downloading it from some other place.

Comment: So, I've found Universal signed apk on Play Console and downloaded on my mac, but how to install it on my phone?

Comment: Ok, I did installed it from Universal Signed APK but the results are the same, https are not working in many places, also Google Sign in is not working either.